# JS or jQuery how to delete key-value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, key-value

Using JS or jQuery how to delete the key-value pair which the value is of type “`Null`” & `""`.
e.g.
before:

```
Object {style: "fruit", origin: "Thailand", day: "18d", color: "", weight: null}
```

alter:

```
Object {style: "fruit", origin: "Thailand", day: "18d"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Loop through the object's properties
2. Remove a property from an object

There are lots of ways to do the first, covered by [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object). Assuming you only care about "own" (non-inherited) properties, I'd probably use `Object.keys` to get an array of property names and then loop that.

The second is done with the `delete` operator.

So:

```
Object.keys(theObject).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = theObject[key];
    if (value === "" || value === null) {
        delete theObject[key];
    }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var theObject = {
  style: "fruit",
  origin: "Thailand",
  day: "18d",
  color: "",
  weight: null
};
console.log("Before:", JSON.stringify(theObject, null, 2));
Object.keys(theObject).forEach(function(key) {
  var value = theObject[key];
  if (value === "" || value === null) {
    delete theObject[key];
  }
});
console.log("After:", JSON.stringify(theObject, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for..in` to go through the loop to find which key has `null` or `""`.

Then use `delete` to delete the key

```
var myObj = {
  style: "fruit",
  origin: "Thailand",
  day: "18d",
  color: "",
  weight: null
}

for(var keys in myObj){
 if(myObj[keys] ===null || myObj[keys] === ""){
  delete myObj[keys]
 }
}
console.log(myObj)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/etofd5c7/)

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution by iterating threw the keys of your object and pushing properties matching in a resulting Array :

```
var input = {style: "fruit", origin: "Thailand", day: "18d", color: "", weight: null};
var keys = Object.keys(input);
var result = {};
keys.forEach(key => {if (input[key] != null && input[key] != "") result[key] = input[key]});
console.log(result); // { style: 'fruit', origin: 'Thailand', day: '18d' }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var yourObj={style: "fruit", origin: "Thailand", day: "18d", color: "", weight: null}

for(var attr in yourObj){
  if(!yourObj[attr]){
    delete yourObj[attr]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done using this code :

```
var map = {style: "fruit", origin: "Thailand", day: "18d", color: "", weight: null};

for (var i in map){
    if(map[i]==null || map[i]==""){
       delete(map[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.